# Por qué el servidor apache si encuentra la ruta a un servlet cuando se utiliza la dependencia javax v7, pero no cuando se usa jakarta.servlet v5.0.0

Tags: apache, java-ee, servlets, error404

Proyecto java web con maven y uso del IDE Netbeans 15, la versión del software utilizado es: Java 1.8.0_351, Apache TomEE Plus 8.0.15.

Cree el proyecto con la siguiente estructura:

- CRUD_Productos

  - src

    - main

      - java

        - com

          - ipn

            - mx

              - controlador

                - producto

                  - ListadoProductos.java
      - webapp

        - WEB-INF
        - META-INF

          - context.xml
        - index.html
  - pom.xml
  - nbactions.xml
  - nb-configuration.xml

Y mi código del archivo index.html es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" ></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <header>
                Proyecto 1.
            </header>
            <div>
                Aplicación para la administración de productos.
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="ListadoProductos">Productos</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Mientras que el del archivo ListadoProductos.java (Servlet) es:

```
/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/JSP_Servlet/Servlet.java to edit this template
 */
package com.ipn.mx.controlador.producto;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author Cristian
 */
@WebServlet(name = "ListadoProductos", value = "/ListadoProductos")
public class ListadoProductos extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try ( PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet ListadoProductos</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet ListadoProductos at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

El archivo pom.xml está de la siguiente forma:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ipn.mx</groupId>
    <artifactId>CRUD_Productos</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>CRUD_Productos</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>-->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Entonces, como mencioné anteriormente, si ejecutó el proyecto usando la dependencia javax, ejecuta correctamente al tratar de dirigirme al servlet, pero cuando lo intento con jakarta.servlet arroja lo siguiente:

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
> Type Status Report
>
> Message El recurso requerido [/CRUD_Productos/ListadoProductos] no se encuentra disponible
>
> Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
>
> Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/9.0.74 (8.0.15)

Lo único que se me ocurre es que sea error de compatibilidad, pero investigando la compatibilidad de los software que utilizó en la página de Apache TomEE, al parecer no debería haber problema, además ya había utilizado en otra computadora Apache TomEE 8.0.9, java 1.8.0_371, Netbeans 12 y si funcionaba con ambos: jakarta.servlet 5.0.0 y javax. Entonces, alguién sabrá qué está ocurriendo?

Answer (score 0):

ya resolví el problema. Tal vez a alguien le ayude saber que aunque existe documentación, generalmente tienden a olvidar o especificar ciertas cosas, por ejemplo, en la otra computadora que mencioné que había usado una configuración similar, pues resulta que utilice java 1.8.0_371, Apache Netbeans 12 y Apache TomEE Plus 9.0.0-M7, es por eso que antes pude usar jakarta.servlet, ya que TomEE 9.x si lo soporta. Pero una pequeña incongruencia con la documentación es que se menciona que TomEE 9 solo soporta java 11 y yo lo trabaje con Java 8.